# parallel k-means in R

Tags: r, parallel-processing, parallel-foreach

I am trying to understand how to parallelize some of my code using R. So, in the following example I want to use k-means to cluster data using 2,3,4,5,6 centers, while using 20 iterations. 
Here is the code:

```
library(parallel)
library(BLR)

data(wheat)

parallel.function <- function(i) {
    kmeans( X[1:100,100], centers=?? , nstart=i )
}

out <- mclapply( c(5, 5, 5, 5), FUN=parallel.function )
```

How can we parallel simultaneously the iterations and the centers? 
How to track the outputs, assuming I want to keep all the outputs from k-means across all, iterations and centers, just to learn how?

Comment: Another option is using the [biganalytics package](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/biganalytics/biganalytics.pdf) In page 4 you can find the ```bigkmeans()``` function.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This looked very simple to me at first ... and then i tried it. After a lot of monkey typing and face palming during my lunch break however, I arrived at this:

```
library(parallel)
library(BLR)

data(wheat)

mc = mclapply(2:6, function(x,centers)kmeans(x, centers), x=X)
```

It looks right though I didn't check how sensible the clustering was.

```
> summary(mc)
     Length Class  Mode
[1,] 9      kmeans list
[2,] 9      kmeans list
[3,] 9      kmeans list
[4,] 9      kmeans list
[5,] 9      kmeans list
```

On reflection the command syntax seems sensible - although a lot of other stuff that failed seemed reasonable too...The examples in the help documentation are maybe not that great.

Hope it helps.

**EDIT** 
As requested here is that on two variables `nstart` and `centers`

```
(pars = expand.grid(i=1:3, cent=2:4))

  i cent
1 1    2
2 2    2
3 3    2
4 1    3
5 2    3
6 3    3
7 1    4
8 2    4
9 3    4

L=list()
# zikes horrible
pars2=apply(pars,1,append, L)
mc = mclapply(pars2, function(x,pars)kmeans(x, centers=pars$cent,nstart=pars$i ), x=X)

> summary(mc)
      Length Class  Mode
 [1,] 9      kmeans list
 [2,] 9      kmeans list
 [3,] 9      kmeans list
 [4,] 9      kmeans list
 [5,] 9      kmeans list
 [6,] 9      kmeans list
 [7,] 9      kmeans list
 [8,] 9      kmeans list
 [9,] 9      means list
```

How'd you like them apples?

Comment: Stephen Henderson, Thank you so much for your answer -- However the challenge, at least for me, is to simultaneously parallel the iterations and the number of clusters i.e " kmeans(x, centers,nstart =?) " Again thank you & i appreciate your help

Comment: @hema Challenge Accepted!

Comment: NB note for sensible speed up you should control how many cores you are actually using based on what you have and a bit of testing...

Comment: Stephen Henderson : Very interesting answer, i learned something new from you today. I will apply your idea in one of my functions that required 2 for loops " takes forever". I will accept your answer late today.

Comment: Stephen Henderson: can we exchange emails, i am trying to apply what you just did in my "real life function"--- it looks like i am missing something. Can i share i did with you then we can work this problem together --  Here is my email : ielbasyoni@gmail, i will understand if you don't have time. thanks again

Comment: @hema my mail is on my profile. If you send a brief reproducible version, I'll have a look.. No promises though, I haven't used mclapply much either.

Answer (score 5):

There's a CRAN package called [knor](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/knor/index.html) that is derived from a [research paper](https://arxiv.org/abs/1606.08905) that improves the performance using a memory efficient variant of Elkan's pruning algorithm. It's an order of magnitude faster than everything in these answers.

```
install.packages("knor")
require(knor)
iris.mat <- as.matrix(iris[,1:4])
k <- length(unique(iris[, dim(iris)[2]])) # Number of unique classes
nthread <- 4
kms <- Kmeans(iris.mat, k, nthread=nthread)
```

Comment: Thanks for pointing this out. Knor is fast!  I highly recommend this for anyone reading this thread. Now blowing up far fewer HPC nodes for far less time.

Answer (score 1):

You may use parallel to try K-Means from different random starting points on multiple cores.

The code below is an example. (K=K in K-means, N= number of random starting points, C = number of cores you would like to use)

```
suppressMessages( library("Matrix") )
suppressMessages( library("irlba") )
suppressMessages( library("stats") )
suppressMessages( library("cluster") )
suppressMessages( library("fpc") )
suppressMessages( library("parallel") )

#Calculate KMeans results
calcKMeans <- function(matrix, K, N, C){
  #Parallel running from various of random starting points (Using C cores)
  results <- mclapply(rep(N %/% C, C), FUN=function(nstart) kmeans(matrix, K, iter.max=15, nstart=nstart), mc.cores=C);
  #Find the solution with smallest total within sum of square error
  tmp <- sapply(results, function(r){r[['tot.withinss']]})
  km <- results[[which.min(tmp)]]  
  #return cluster, centers, totss, withinss, tot.withinss, betweenss, size
  return(km)
}

runKMeans <- function(fin_uf, K, N, C, 
                      #fout_center, fout_label, fout_size, 
                      fin_record=NULL, fout_prediction=NULL){
  uf = read.table(fin_uf)
  km = calcKMeans(uf, K, N, C)
  rm(uf)
  #write.table(km$cluster, file=fout_label, row.names=FALSE, col.names=FALSE)
  #write.table(km$center, file=fout_center, row.names=FALSE, col.names=FALSE)
  #write.table(km$size, file=fout_size, row.names=FALSE, col.names=FALSE)
  str(km)

  return(km$center)
}
```

Hope it helps!